# Insert into related tables

Tags: mysql, triggers, relational-database

I have 2 tables with one-to-many relations, and I need the following insert:

```
A - source table
nr  Name
1   a
1   b
1   c
2   d
2   e
546 abc
546 asd
546 qwe

B - results table
FK_ID Name
...
6     a
6     b
6     c
7     d
7     e
8     abc
8     asd
8     qwe

C - table with unique IDs
ID
...
5 
6 (new)
7 (new)
8 (new)
```

I take the rows from **source table**, insert them in **results table**, and for each group, I need to insert a row in the **table with unique IDs** and update the inserted rows in **results table** so I have relation between B and C (ID is auto incrementing in C).

Should I make a BEFORE/AFTER INSERT trigger, or there is a faster way?(>100k rows)

**Edit:**

I removed the foreign key from B, so I can insert anything in B, but step 2 takes way too much now (3k rows / 10 minutes).

```
-- step 1
insert into B(..., helperColumn)
select ..., 1 from A;


-- step 2
myloop: WHILE true DO
    set @updateID = (select ID from B where helperColumn = 1 limit 1);
    if @updateID is null then
        LEAVE myloop;
    end if;

    insert into C(...)
    values(...);

    set @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    update B
    set ID = @id, helperColumn = 0
    where ID = @updateID
    and helperColumn = 1;

END WHILE;
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to organize things so that for each group of rows in the source table A with the same `nr` value, you want to (a) insert a record into table C to obtain a new unique ID for the group, and then (b) you want to insert the records from the source table A into the results table B, allocating the new unique ID to each of the records in the group? If not, please explain — probably by editing the question rather than an explanation in extra comments.

Comment: It's relatively easy to see a procedural solution: `SELECT DISTINCT nr FROM A;` collecting the results in variable `nr_val`, one at a time.  For each such value returned, do: `INSERT INTO C` to get the new unique ID in variable `new_id`, then `INSERT INTO B SELECT new_id, old_data FROM A WHERE nr = nr_val;` and `DELETE FROM A WHERE nr = nr_val;`.  I'm not sure what's the best way to package that in MySQL.  The difficulty with making that into set-oriented operations is the step which matches the new ID from B with the main insert operation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried something like that, but it's very slow when I have ~1M rows, because: `For each such value returned, do...`

Maybe its faster with a trigger on B, or I add a new culomn in B and do something like 1.`insert into B select from A` 2.`for each...insert into C, update B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution was this:

```
insert into B(FK_ID, ...)
select InsertC(nr), ... from A;
```

InsertC is a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION `InsertC`(pOldID BIGINT) RETURNS bigint(20)
BEGIN

    set @newID = (select ID from B where OldID = pOldID);

    if @newID is null then
        insert into C(..., OldID)
        values(..., pOldID);

        set @newID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    end if;

    RETURN @newID;
END
```

I still needed a new column in B (OldID + index on it), but this is much faster than before.